# How do I put a description in an aws lambda thru aws web console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

From AWS, I created a lambda in aws console the description is blank after it was created, is there any way to edit and put a description from the aws web console? I can't find if there's any field to do that.

here's the screenshot
[image: awslambda list does not have description]

Comment: Same problem here, AWS web has missing functionality...

Answer (score 5):

Currently
Lambda >Functions>Actual Function>> Configuration >General Configuration>
(Description)Edit

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Edit the function in the console
- Scroll down to **Basic settings**
- Click **Edit**
- Enter a **Description**

Answer (score 1):

For odd reasons at the moment of this post, you can find this setting in a surprising place

- Lambda >
- Functions >
- YourLambdaName >
- Configuration >
- Execution role > Edit >
- Basic settings > Description

After you enter a description the name of the field is changed from `Execution role` to `General configuration`. Probably in near future AWS is going to change this UI behavior